# Can I use Blender to create a virtual museum/gallery to exibit my students paintings and sculptures?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, light, geometry

I am just getting started with Blender. My goal is create a virtual museum/gallery in which I will be able to exibit the artistic creations of my middle and highschool students. These will be paintings, sculptures and pottery.

I would like to begin with a very simple room. I would like to have the ability to adjust the lighting (floods, spot lights).  The walls are plain for display of paintings/drawings. I want to create movable pedestals for for the display of sculptures and pottery.

Is blender the appropriate tool for this task?

Thank you very much for any and all assistance!

Craig

Comment: Blender can import 3D scans and 2.83 alpha supports VR as shown in the following video >> https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hTro_QBEXR4 so I'd say yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that in blender. The simplest way to import the images is to enable the "import images as planes" addon. Then just create the geometry of the rooms and add lights as needed.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping that I was on the right path.

Answer (score 3):

You can do in blender if your output has to be a video, image render or a 3d models, but if you want to create a self-working program that let other people navigate in the virtual museum as a video-game (with mouse and keyboard), I suggest to use other programs (unity or unreal engine).

Comment: Yes, I do want to people to be able to navigate thru the virtual museum. Indeed, that was going to be my next question. Regardless, I am going to learn how to use blendar because it appears to be an incredible tool. Thank you for you advice!!

Comment: You can check "blender game":


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfzy69JPRVI

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick with blender, you can check blender 2.79 that has a game engine that enables what you are looking for:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zzIHObjJnc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfzy69JPRVI

Otherwise there is also this project that enable game engine on blender 2.8: so you can use real time render engine EEVEE:

https://upbge.org/

Comment: This is really good information and will help me to make an informed decision about what I will eventualy do. Both videos are examples that will work well. I will start simple and eventually change things. I want a space in which to exhibit my students Art Work, both 2D and 3D. I am assuming that I will be able to import either 3D rendered images ofthe sculptures or fotos of the paintings and drawings. Is this correct?

Comment: I am going to learn how to use Blender, regardless of how I create a virtual gallery space. My immediate goal is to understand what tools I need to learn that will enable me to do that. Thank you again.

Comment: It's really easy to create an environment like rooms that will host your arts. It's simple to insert images of painting and add some 3d elements to simulate a picture frame. It will be a lot harder to transfer into blender a 3d model that comes from a real object (you can use photogrammetry to do it, but it's quite a complex procedure).

Comment: I should be able to begin this project this weekend, with a serious dive into things after the semester enes on the 12 of June. I am planning on spending the next couple months learning about 3D modeling and working on a virtual museaum as I described.

Comment: You had mentioned using Unity or Unreal Engine for this purpose. Would this make things easier? I will most certainly learn and use Blendar, but I do want to try and focus my energies, particularly as I am learning, on the best strategy.

Comment: I don't know unity or UE. What you can do for sure is to start modelling in Blender and later on import models into other software to create the interactive program.

Comment: check this (paid models): https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/museum-vr-vol-i-ancient-greece-rome (and youtube preview --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85EFbOlpbdg )